# How to clear input value after first letter?

Tags: jquery, input

I want to clear all character after the first letters in the values of inputs using jQuery. I have this:

```
<form id="form">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-one[]" value="A some text">A some text</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-one[]" value="B some text">B some text</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-one[]" value="C some text">C some text</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-one[]" value="D some text">D some text</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-one[]" value="Е some text">Е some text</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-one[]" value="F some text">F some text</label>

    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

I want the result to be this:

```
<form id="form">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-one[]" value="A">A some text</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-one[]" value="B">B some text</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-one[]" value="C">C some text</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-one[]" value="D">D some text</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-one[]" value="Е">Е some text</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-one[]" value="F">F some text</label>

    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Why not clear it before populating the form? That way the user will never see what the values were (assuming that's important to your logic). Using JS means that they will still be able to see the values that were originally loaded in the source of the page

Comment: i have this form now and want to clear it before send the form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by providing a function to `val()` which returns only the first character of the current value:

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').val(function(i, v) {
  return v[0];
})

// just to show it works:
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
  console.log(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-one[]" value="A some text">A some text</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-one[]" value="B some text">B some text</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-one[]" value="C some text">C some text</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-one[]" value="D some text">D some text</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-one[]" value="Е some text">Е some text</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-one[]" value="F some text">F some text</label>

    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

However, it would arguably be better to do this in your code which populates the form source. This way the user will never see what the values were (assuming that's important to your logic). Using JS means that they will still be able to see the values that were originally loaded in the source of the page.

Comment: You want to do this before submitting: `$("#form").on("submit",function() {
    });`

Comment: I need only first letters. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can change the values before submitting them:

```
$("#submitForm").click(function() {

   $("#valueA").val($("#valueA").val().charAt(0));
   //continue for other values as well (b to f)
   $("#form").submit();

});
```

Your form will be changed to:

```
<form id="form">
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="valueA" name="checkbox-one[]" value="A some text">A some text</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="valueB" name="checkbox-one[]" value="B some text">B some text</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="valueC" name="checkbox-one[]" value="C some text">C some text</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="valueD" name="checkbox-one[]" value="D some text">D some text</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="valueE" name="checkbox-one[]" value="Е some text">Е some text</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" id="valueF" name="checkbox-one[]" value="F some text">F some text</label>

  <button id="submitForm">Submit</button>
</form>
```

It still can be optimized as I saw the answers from other users.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
  $("form" ).submit(function( event ) {
     $("input").each(function(){
     $(this).val($(this).val().charAt(0))
   });
 });
```